# How to make Proguard ignore external libraries?

Tags: android, proguard, android-library

I want to use Proguard mainly for obfuscation reasons.

My problem is that I have three libraries, Twitter4J and two signpost libraries. These libraries caused errors when I tried to create an signed APK.  To get over this I put the following in the `proguard.config` file...

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.** 
-dontwarn org.slf4j.** 
-dontwarn com.sun.syndication.io.**
-dontwarn com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.*
```

While this got rid of the errors in the console, when i loaded my signed APK onto my mobile phone it instantly crashed.  The DDMS said this was due to a class not found in Twitter4J.

Getting rid of the `"dontwarns"` above did not help.  Neither did adding `dontshrink  dontoptimise`.

I would  like Proguard to completely ignore the libraries (as they are open source anyway).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 73):

Try this:

```
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
```

Cf post from @CaspNZ:
[Android Proguard with external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870773/android-proguard-with-external-jar/6870844#6870844)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I first ignored this post as I thought my errors would not be solved by this, but somehow it did. I just don't know the magic of proguard...

Comment: @Boy plz reply in android studio where to add these lines, either in 'proguard-project.txt' or 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: @ShirishHerwade just checked and I've put it in the proguard-rules.txt. Check your build.gradle for the correct file

Comment: Two asterisks don't compile anymore. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 17):

You should be able to add to the proguard.cfg the following lines to exclude all classes within a package (and subpackages)

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-keep interface org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-keep enum org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-keep class org.slf4j.**
-keep interface org.slf4j.**
-keep enum org.slf4j.**
-keep class com.sun.syndication.io.**
-keep interface com.sun.syndication.io.**
-keep enum com.sun.syndication.io.**
-keep class com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.**
-keep interface com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.**
-keep enum com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.**
```

Comment: Hi @Nic Strong,  hanks for the reply.  I added the code but when I tried to export the signed APK a lot of errors typically like "[2011-10-11 15:11:00 - canonV0003PRO] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64".  Any other suggestions greatly appreciated.  Mel

Comment: Did you also add oauth.signpost.** to the list of packages to keep?

Comment: @NicStrong plz reply in android studio where to add these lines, either in 'proguard-project.txt' or 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Two asterisks don't compile anymore. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that you should sync your project with Gradle files after adding proguard rules, otherwise they may not work.