# Jsoup doesn't work inside APK

Tags: java, android, jsoup, apk

I have tried billions of different manners to solve this but no success.

I have this simple app doing some Gets on a web url, which works perfectly, except when I build and sing the apk file and install on device.

I wonder if someone would have any idea of what is wrong because at this point I am giving up this thing.

My code:

Java:

```
   String url = urlBase + "/" + moeda;
    Document html = Jsoup.connect(url).
            timeout(Util.TIMEOUT_CONEXAO).
            userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0").
            header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8").
            header("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3").
            header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate").
            header("Connection", "keep-alive").
            header("Cookie", "_ga=GA1.2.1944138861.1459771567; _gat=1").
            header("Host", targetHost).
            referrer("http://www.google.com").
            ignoreHttpErrors(true).
            get();
```

**proguard-android.txt**

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}

-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```

Again, when I run directly to the device (normal or debug), it works perfectly, once I do the same but installing from a singed apk file when I press the button to call an AsyncTask to do the get the app breaks, no exception is throw so I cant even know what is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but I've had issues with JSoup and ProGuard and solved [it here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18045587/2650847).

Comment: "the app breaks" - what does that mean?

Comment: "Breaks", means "a button is touched and the app stops with the message 'the app XXXXXX has stopped'"