# How to get holiday by date for specific country?

Tags: android

I am looked for library or other solutions to show holiday by date for specific country. Like JollyDay but for Android. Because JollyDay needs javax.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902943/how-to-include-additional-javax-packages-in-android-app-with-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

I have use [This](http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/) site - getting info using Json. It does not cover All countries - It might suit your needs.